# SmartPhone that can have two SIM cards in EU

Tags: smartphones

I already have the Samsung S8 and now my boss at work gave me an iPhone 6 as a work phone so now I have two phones just to keep two phone numbers. It would be more convenient if a phone could use two SIM cards and two phone numbers with one phone. IIUC Lenovo produces such a phone but high-end smartphones usually don't have this feature.

Can you recommend what I should get? I'd like to know a few alternatives but I have no particular budget restrictions, I can afford a couple of hundreds of USD for this.

Comment: Any budget restrictions or requirements except "needs to support dual-sim"?

Comment: @SEJPM No but I'd like to know a few alternatives.

Comment: The Nokia 8 should be shippable with dual-sim support and I expect the Nokia 9 to have this trait as well on release.

Comment: https://www.gsmarena.com/search.php3 is a useful phone finding utility with the ability to specify you want a Dual SIM phone.